# want to get delete or update only if you had created the product in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, express, backend

I want to update or delete product only if the user had created the product otherwise unable to delete or update

here is my product schema ;-

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    name:{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    category:{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    description :{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    price: {
        type : Number,
        required : true
    },
    seller: {
        type : String,
        required : false,
        unique: true
    },
    image: {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    Date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

here is my user schema :-

```
const registerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    username:{
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required : true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password :{
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    Date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

here is my user login routes :-

```
router.post(
  "/login",
  body("email", "email should exist").exists(),
  body("password", "password should exist").exists(),
  async (req, res) => {
    const {email , password} = req.body;
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }

      const user = await Register.findOne({email : email})
      if(!user){
        return res.status(404).json({error :"Please Enter correct credential"})
      }
      const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
        if(!valid){
        return res.status(404).json({error :"Please Enter correct credential"})
      }
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
          { _id: user._id },
          "process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN"
      );
      return res.status(200).json({ accessToken });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log({error})
    }
  }
);
```

here is my product route :-

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const register = await Register.find();
    if (!register) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "register not found" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ register });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

//posting signup data

router.post(
  "/signup",
  body("email", "enter valid email").isEmail(),
  body("email", "email should exist").exists(),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }
      const { username, email } = req.body;
      secHash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
      console.log(secHash)

      const user = await Register.findOne({ email });

      if (user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "User already Exist" });
      }

      const register = new Register({
        username,
        email,
        password: secHash,
      });

      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        { _id: Register._id },
        "process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN"
      );

      if (!register) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "user not created" });
      }

      await register.save();
      return res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

// Creating Login 

router.post(
  "/login",
  body("email", "email should exist").exists(),
  body("password", "password should exist").exists(),
  async (req, res) => {
    const {email , password} = req.body;
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }

      const user = await Register.findOne({email : email})
      if(!user){
        return res.status(404).json({error :"Please Enter correct credential"})
      }
      const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
        if(!valid){
        return res.status(404).json({error :"Please Enter correct credential"})
      }
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
          { _id: user._id },
          "process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN"
      );
      return res.status(200).json({ accessToken });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log({error})
    }
  }
);
```

more detail:- i will login then there i am getting all the fetched product .
the problem i want to get resolve is i want to make delete or update only that product that i have created

it will be great help if you help me I'm stuck in this problem for 5 days i don,t know what to do ..

Comment: It's like all the products is public and I want to allow users to delete or update only the product the they created

Answer (score 0):

When a user create product, you can save a `_id` of the user in the product Schema, while deleting a product use `findOneAndUpdate` mongo query.

Comment: I am a beginner can you please elaborate how to save _id and push into product schema

Comment: send me the code when u r adding the product